# Declare a string type with a set of possible values

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I know that the following works:

```
interface Travel {
  travelClass: 'economy' | 'business' | 'first';
  username?: String;
}
```

Now, I want to extract the travelClass so that I can reuse it at other places,  something like this:-

```
type TravelClass 'economy' | 'business' | 'first'
```

However, it is not compiling.

Comment: This is invalid Go syntax. Probably tagged the wrong language?

Comment: Thanks @icza you are right. I fixed it to typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`type` requires the use of a `=`.

```
type TravelClass  = 'economy' | 'business' | 'first'
```